# Intellij's javaFX scene builder not working

Tags: intellij-idea, scenebuilder, intellij-15

When I open .fxml file in IntelliJ IDEA 15 and swich to the SceneBuilder tab, I allways get an error page. I have checked a path to the SceneBuilder app and it is valid. I also can run the Scene Builder app without any problems. Can someone help me with this?

The error it throws me on the Scene Builder tab:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderCreatorImpl.create(SceneBuilderCreatorImpl.java:35)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderEditor.addSceneBuilder(SceneBuilderEditor.java:204)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderEditor.access$700(SceneBuilderEditor.java:34)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderEditor$ExternalChangeListener.checkContent(SceneBuilderEditor.java:338)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderEditor.initSceneBuilder(SceneBuilderEditor.java:180)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderEditor.selectNotify(SceneBuilderEditor.java:252)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite$1$1.run(EditorComposite.java:148)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite$1.selectionChanged(EditorComposite.java:154)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:116)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:368)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:355)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:341)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:334)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:42)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$2.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:223)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.selectionChanged(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite$3.run(EditorComposite.java:229)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$15$1.run(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1055)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.a(FocusManagerImpl.java:672)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.g(FocusManagerImpl.java:656)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.c(FocusManagerImpl.java:626)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.access$200(FocusManagerImpl.java:60)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl$11.run(FocusManagerImpl.java:522)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2316)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:500)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:495)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:64)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$15.run(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1052)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.BusyObject$Impl$Simple.execute(BusyObject.java:123)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.notifyPublisher(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1048)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite.a(EditorComposite.java:224)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite.access$600(EditorComposite.java:67)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite$MyChangeListener.stateChanged(EditorComposite.java:410)
at com.intellij.ui.JBTabsPaneImpl.a(JBTabsPaneImpl.java:81)
at com.intellij.ui.JBTabsPaneImpl.access$100(JBTabsPaneImpl.java:36)
at com.intellij.ui.JBTabsPaneImpl$2.selectionChanged(JBTabsPaneImpl.java:67)
at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.fireSelectionChanged(JBTabsImpl.java:965)
at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.executeSelectionChange(JBTabsImpl.java:918)
at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl._setSelected(JBTabsImpl.java:882)
at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.select(JBTabsImpl.java:864)
at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.TabLabel$1.mousePressed(TabLabel.java:89)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6532)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4522)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.f(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader
at     org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderKitWrapper.create(SceneBuilderKitWrapper.java:19)
... 85 more
```

Comment: I have the exact same error.

Note that I downloaded the build of SceneBuilder maintained by gluonhq.com rather than building from sources.  It could be that that version is not recognized by IntelliJ.

Comment: This helped me http://stackoverflow.com/a/33595441/4663544