# Error "Module not found error' on custom module

Tags: java, javafx

I've created a custom module which I want to use in another JavaFX application.

When compiling the JavaFX application, I got an error "Module not found: com.mycompany.mymodule"

in my JavaFX module-info.java

```
module com.mycompany.demofx {
    requires com.mycompany.mymodule;
}
```

How can I fix this? Thanx

Comment: If local, don't neglect to 'install' the dependency, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76276885/230513).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [_Error own Maven Dependency to new FXML project_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76260125/230513).

Comment: A [guide for using code from your own dependent module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76311539/javafx-custom-component-usage-in-scenebuilder/76317530#76317530), when using Maven.  That guide is more complex then what you need, as it is for a custom component used in SceneBuilder, but the modular aspects of the solution are the same.