# Problem with connecting a .jar file to a JavaFX project

Tags: java, maven, javafx, module, jar

The following problem has arisen.
I made a `.jar` file from one of my projects, which needs to be connected to another project. In another project, I connected it via <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> -> <kbd>Libraries</kbd> and <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> -> <kbd>Modules</kbd>.
IntelliJ then suggested adding requires Figures to the module-info.java file.
When compiling, the following error appears:

> java: module not found: Figures.

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

I tried to connect as a module in <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> -> <kbd>Modules</kbd> and as like library in <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> -> <kbd>Libraries</kbd>. Tried to delete the module-info.java, but it doesn`t work without it.

The structure of the Figures.jar
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5VVH.png)

The directory `META-INF` has only one file `MANIFEST.MF` with:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: App
```

Comment: Do you have a module named `FigureTest`?  You can use the [`jar` command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jar.html) with the `--describe-module` to find the name of the module for a jar file.

Comment: Please include the module info as text in your question.  You can also include an IDE screenshot as you have, but any relevant textual information (code, module descriptors, error messages, etc) in the screenshot must also be in the question as text, formatted as code.

Comment: If you are using Maven to source your dependencies (including ones you created), then they should be listed in the IDE under `External Libraries` as `Maven: ...` dependencies, however this is not the case with your `FigureTest-1.0.0.jar` dependency.

Comment: Yes, i have Maven: org.testing:FigureTest:1.0.0 in External Libraries. dependencies of Maven also see that. When i clicked on requires FigureTest(ctrl + LMB) it refers to the .jar file in the External Libraries. But if i clicked "Run" happens this: 
java: module not found: FigureTest. I really don`t understand what i need to do, because i tried all methods i know as i describe above.

Comment: I have a screenshot of the IDE above

Comment: Screenshots of text are not good enough [for so many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: "Maven: org.testing:FigureTest:1.0.0 in External Libraries. dependencies of Maven also see that." -> I don't see that, it isn't in your screenshot.  If added by Maven automatically the library *should not also be added manually to the IDE libraries*.

Comment: Provide your `pom.xml` as text formatted as code.  Provide the `module-info.java` as text formatted as code.  Provide the output of the jar `--describe-module` command on the dependent jar file.  Where did the jar come from? Do you have source code for it?  Is the source code a Maven or Gradle project? "load the .jar file into .m2(local maven repos)" -> Provide the exact command you executed for that.  Edit the question to add *all* these things.

Comment: Do it. Sorry, but i dk where do i need to use this: --describe-module?

Comment: The MAIN TASK is HOW TO CONNECT THE .jar FILE TO MY FiguresFX PROJECT. Maby i dont`t know some ways ho to do it in a diffetent.

Comment: Can you post *both* `module-info.java` files? The one for the required module and the one for the module that requires it? I am guessing the one you posted is for the latter.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont have file module-info.java for FigureTest. Yeah, i think about that can be a problem, so i need to create this file or what? Just when i try to do that, it show me that .jar is Readonly and i cant create any files. 
Maybe then I can somehow do it at the initial stage of creating the .jar file? But what if I created it automatically via Maven -> Install. :/

Comment: What is the purpose of the FigureTest jar?  Is it *only* for unit testing, or is it used at runtime.  If it is for unit testing, then change the dependency scope from `compile` to `test` and reimport the project into the IDE and it should work for testing as modern Maven and IDE versions are smart enough not to treat test code as modules.

Comment: But if you use it at runtime don’t do that, instead you need to determine the name of the module and ensure it is on the module path and added as a required module. `jar —describe-module <jar file name>` will tell you the module name to put in your module info.  The jar file can be found in your `.m2` repository.

Comment: Provide the pom.xml of the project used to create the FigureTest jar.  Does the jar file have a META-INF file that sets an [automatic module name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module#:~:text=The%20module%20descriptor%20for%20an,other%20modules%20in%20the%20configuration.)?

Comment: Is the groupId for FigureTest really org.testing rather than com.figures like your FiguresFX project?  (It could be, I am just checking because the group name is unusual).

Comment: Sorry for that, but now i dont need to connect FigureTest.jar to my project. Instead of this i need to connect Figures.jar. This is the same project to FigureTest, but without testing things and it dont using Maven. So, i created .jar in Project Structure -> Artifacts, then Build -> Artifacts and i have a .jar file. But there is nothing like groupId or artifactId. So, how can i connect this .jar to my JavaFX project. I apologize as much as possible, but i cant cope without help :(

Comment: If you don't need FigureTest.jar, then don't `requires FigureTest;` as a module.  If you instead have `Figures.jar` and it is on the *module path* NOT the *classpath* and it is *not* a modular jar (has no `module-info.java`) and it does *not* have an automatic module name defined in the META-INF (see the prior comment), then the automatic module name will be derived from the jar file name and you can write `requires Figures;` in your module-info.  Or if it is just on the classpath, don't refer to it in module-info at all and it will be picked up from the classpath.

Comment: If you want to have a maven dependency on Figures.jar in your Maven project, then you need to install the Figures jar in your maven repository.  If you have source code that produced Figures.jar as a maven project you can run maven install on that project and it will put the Figures jar in your repository.  If you don't have source code that produces the Figures.jar but just a jar binary, [manually install the jar in your repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) and refer to it in your maven project using the coordinates you provided on install.

Comment: If you don't want the Figures.jar as a Maven dependency you can add it as an IDE library, but, given your project is already a Maven project, I *do not recommend that approach* and won't outline it here as I don't use it or recommend it and I am not familiar with it.

Comment: So. If i add a Figures.jar as a module in Project Structure -> Modules and the add a `requires Figures` in the module-info.java i have the same exception: `module not found`.
But if i add it like a library in Project Structure -> Libraries and dont add `requires Figures`, i dont know how to import classes. Im writing `import..` and it doesnt suggest anything automatically. 
The structure of the jar im attaching on the screenshot

Comment: Well, I solved the problem by completely rebuilding the javaFX project and adding some dependencies. The question is closed, thank you all

Answer (score 2):

You can see this guide for creating your own maven and java modules that you reuse in other projects:

- [JavaFX custom component usage in SceneBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76311539/javafx-custom-component-usage-in-scenebuilder/76317530#76317530)

That guide also goes into how you create custom components and import them into SceneBuilder, so it covers more info than what you need, but the rest of the stuff around how to do this with Java and Maven, without SceneBuilder is still applicable to your case.

Comment: Thanks, but it is really not what i need. There is mostly a problem of connecting .jar file to JavaFX. I simply need to connect the .jar as library/module or Maven dependency or something else, i don`t know how is right and use the Classes from this .jar.

Comment: @Lion: A related example is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76276885/230513).

Comment: I`ve done all of the steps described in but i have the same exception anyway

Comment: The asker (Lion) provided a comment: "I solved the problem by completely rebuilding the javaFX project and adding some dependencies.".