# Javafx Making a library( custom component )

Tags: java, javafx

I tried making a custom component that I could recycle but I got this exception whenever I try to import the library and run the app using the library.

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module com.example.My_Library contains package javafx.scene.control.cell, module javafx.controls exports package javafx.scene.control.cell to com.example.My_Library
```

this exception is not limited to just `control.cell` but also `javafx.scene.chart`, and `javafx.scene.control`.

The component runs correctly in scene builder and in the component project .

This is the module that I used:

```java
module com.example.My_Library {


    requires javafx.controls;

    requires javafx.fxml;




    exports com.example.My_Library.Components;
    exports com.example.My_Library.Launcher;


    opens com.example.My_Library.Components;
    opens com.example.My_Library.Launcher;
    opens com.example.My_Library.Components.Images;
}
```

The component class:

```java
public class Time_picker extends HBox {
    private Property<LocalTime > time;

    @FXML private  Label time_text;
    @FXML  private  Button minus_button,plus_button;
    @FXML private HBox background;



    public Time_picker(){




            time=new SimpleObjectProperty<>(LocalTime.of(8,0));

            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/example/My_Library/Components/Time_picker.fxml"));
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.setController(this);
        try{
            loader.load();
            plus_button.setOnMouseClicked(event -> increse_time());
            minus_button.setOnMouseClicked(event -> decrease_time());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        update_time();

     }

    private ObjectProperty<Color> backgroundColor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    private ObjectProperty<Color> text_color=new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Color.TRANSPARENT);


    public Color getText_color() {
        return text_color.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Color> text_colorProperty() {
        return text_color;
    }

    public void setText_color(Color text_color) {
        this.text_color.set(text_color);
       this.time_text.setStyle("-fx-text-fill : #"+text_colorProperty().get().toString().replace("0x",""));
    }

    public Color getBackgroundColor() {
        return backgroundColor.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Color> backgroundColorProperty() {
        return backgroundColor;
        }

     public void setBackgroundColor(Color backgroundColor) {
            this.backgroundColor.set(backgroundColor);

           this.background.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #"+backgroundColor.toString().replace("0x",""));
      }




     private void increse_time(){
        time.setValue(time.getValue().plusMinutes(30));
        update_time();
    }

     private void decrease_time(){
         time.setValue(time.getValue().minusMinutes(30));
        update_time();
    }
    private void update_time(){
        time_text.setText(time.getValue().toString());
    }

    public Property<LocalTime> get_time_property(){
        return time;
    }

    public LocalTime getTime() {
        return time.getValue();
    }

    public void setTime(LocalTime time) {
        this.time.setValue(time);
    }

    public Label getTime_text() {
        return time_text;
    }

    public void setTime_text(Label time_text) {
        this.time_text = time_text;
    }

    public Button getMinus_button() {
        return minus_button;
    }

    public void setMinus_button(Button minus_button) {
        this.minus_button = minus_button;
    }

    public Button getPlus_button() {
        return plus_button;
    }

        public void setPlus_button(Button plus_button) {
         this.plus_button = plus_button;
        }
}
```

I didn't try much because I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Do any of your classes in your module have a `package javafx.scene.control.cell;` statement? How are you packaging the library JAR file?

Comment: @Slaw no the class that i shared is the only class besides the launch class which doesnt have it 
i am using the javafx artifact to bundle the jar

Comment: What does `jar -tf <path-to-jar-file>` output?

Comment: @Slaw for some reason the jar command is not recognizable is there any other way to provide the necessary info ?

Comment: @Slaw the thing is other libraries that i downloaded work just fine , so something is wrong with my library structure

Comment: Every .jar file is actually a .zip file, so make a copy of your .jar file, rename the copy so it ends with .zip, and open it with an unzip tool of your choice.  If the archive contains .class files in javafx/scene/control/cell, you have packaged your library incorrectly.

Comment: @VGR id does contain .class files 
how do i fix this and package it correctly ?

Comment: You should edit your question and explain how you are creating your library.  If you’re doing it with an IDE, that IDE may have options for whether to include dependencies in the library.  A library should almost never be a “fat jar.”

Comment: See this info on [creating a custom component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76317530/1155209).  I advise running through all the steps in your environment from the answer then adapting what you learned to your own library (though you don't have to do that if you don't want to).  That example includes import into scene builder, if you don't want that, you can skip those steps.

Comment: Best to follow [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: thanks to all those who commented on my question ,
the answer that was posted by @VGR worked instead of making a fat jar with all the javafx components i made a lightweight jar that contains only the library which is the main thing , using the maven clean install through the question that @
jewelsea mentioned